# Cascading DropdownList in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-editor-web-part

I need to put 2 cascading dropdownlists on the home page in SharePoint 2010. The data have to be populated from the Sharepoint List in both the dropdownlists. I know it can be done easily on InfoPath forms but is there a way to have this functionality on the Webpage as we have in asp.net websites

Answer (score 1):

I just released a javascript utility that will allow you to add 2 or more cascading dropdownlists. You can use this on Webparts or custom aspx pages, and it only requires jQuery.

You will find more details here : http://sylvainlancien.blogspot.fr/2013/11/slnspcascadingdropdown-jquery-cascade.html

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in the past with jQuery - dynamically replace the standard field with a dropdown and then control the content of the second dropdown based on what is selected in the first.

I believe there are also some third party plugins on CodePlex that achieve the same thing.